# How to benchmark the throughput with JMH if the work is performed by different threads?

Tags: java, benchmarking, performance-testing, microbenchmark, jmh

we are not sure how to benchmark a part of our application where multiple threads (producers) write into a single ConcurrentHashMap. Additionally, a single consumer thread switches the map with an empty one if a certain size is reached. The switch of the map is necessary because the producer threads need to write into the map as fast as possible without additional congestion. The consumer thread also processes the elements of the map and stores them in a buffer. Where at the end another thread will send the buffer content to some other component of the application.

It's unclear to us how to measure the time (and corresponding throughput) it takes for elements to be written into the ConcurrentHashMap until they are ready to be send (-> aggregated throughput). For now, we exclude the sending of the elements to ease things up. We know that the throughput is throttled by the map size. However, we want to measure it to compare it with the throughput of future implementations.

So far we investigated the following scenarios:

**Silo-Test**
    This benchmark would measure each step within a single benchmark. Benchmark A: insert elements into Map until size (= batchSize) is reached. Benchmark B: Measure how long it takes for an element to be stored in the buffer.
**Advantage**: relatively easy to realize.
**Drawback**: Thread Interactivity is lost and throughput aggregation is not given by adding Benchmark A and B together.

**Flat-Test**
    Compared to the Silo-Test, all steps are executed within one benchmark (single threaded). First X elements are inserted into the Map, then the Map is switched, X elements are processed and stored into the buffer.
**Advantage**: relatively easy to realize.
**Drawback**: Thread Interactivity is lost and the benchmark can only be run by one thread (-> only one producer) because the current implementation doesn't support switching the map and processing of the elements concurrently.

**Dynamic-Amount-Test** (preferred test)
    The benchmark method will insert a single element into the map per invocation. The consumer thread will be started in the @Setup phase and it will deliver the elements to the buffer during the test. At the benchmark end the gathered count of elements in the buffer are provided to JMH for result calculation instead using the invocations of the benchmark method. We are not aware of such out-of-the-box functionality which allows us to provide the buffer size to JMH at the benchmark end. Most likely we need to modify JMH for this requirement (right?).
**Advantage**: Composed throughput is calculated by JMH
**Drawback**: No Out-of-the-box functionality, JMH modification could be dangerous (measurements influenced, benchmark validity unclear)

Additional Remarks: We also have to deal with non-steady-state benchmarks in this scenario. We thought about using the batching possibility of JMH and test with different sizes.

Thanks in Advance for any constructive response.

Comment: Perhaps http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/0879b862a1a3/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_18_Control.java could be of interest to you?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. We did some testing with the 'Control' but we haven't managed to solve our situation with it.